# What's really happening when we use a method as a parameter by reference?

Tags: c++, memory, pass-by-reference

Suppose this:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int x) : m_someDataMember(x) {}
        ~A() {}
        int& someMethod(){ return m_someDataMember; }

    private:
        int m_someDataMember;
};

class B
{
    public:
    B(){}
    ~B(){}
    void anotherMethod(int& someInt){ /*...*/}
};
```

Now in main,

```
int main(/*..*/)
{
    A a(5);
    B b;
    b.anotherMethod(a.someMethod());
}
```

My question being, what is exactly being received in `anotherMethod()`? Is it the memory address itself of `m_someDataMember` from object a, or the memory address of a copy of `m_someDataMemeber` returned by `a.someMethod()`?

EDIT: Corrected typo, missing `&` in `int& someMethod()`

Comment: Does this at all compile?

Comment: This is not valid C++. Check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: You're not passing the member function as an argument, you're passing the value _returned by_ the member function.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I can't see where in my post am I contradicting your statement.

Comment: A reference stays a reference, no copies.

Comment: The title of your post.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Oh? Isn't in my example a method being used as a parameter, in which definition it happens to be a reference?

Comment: @roymcclure, Taking a function by reference as a parameter would be `void foo(int(&func)(int));` or equivalent. It's very different from taking an `int` by reference. Whether that `int` is the return value of a function makes no real difference.

Comment: @chris As I explained to Captain, the "reference" word here makes...ehm.. reference, to the parameter, not to the funcion.

Comment: The title of your post doesn't match the contents or the actual problem. This may make it difficult for others to find, confuse them, or cause them to dismiss it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is exactly being received in anotherMethod()?

A *reference* to that **same variable** is received.

> Is it the memory address itself of m_someDataMember from object a
>    or the memory address of a copy of m_someDataMemeber returned by a.someMethod()?

That reference *may be* a memory address, but C++ doesn't dictate *how* the compiler must implement references.  The entire class could exist in a CPU register as well, in which case it has no memory address.

But a copy of `m_someDataMember` is **not** made.  It refers to the same variable.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I didn't know that reference implementation was up to the compiler. Your answer is exactly what I was after and the only useful reply by the way.

Comment: @roymcclure I'm glad you found an answer.  It seems that the many other replies **were** useful in helping you notice that your question had a typo, making it unanswerable.  You probably don't want a reputation for slighting most of the people who try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a compiler error as you are trying to bind a non `const` reference to a temporary object.

See this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f602717dcfc50a9)

You can fix this by either having `someMethod()` return a reference which you might not want to do or you can take a `const` reference.

See this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c50bf7753f252b63) of using a `const` reference

**Edit based on OP changes**:

If you have a function that returns a reference and you call that function in the parameter list of another function then that function will be referencing whatever variable the first function returned.  No copy will be made in this instance.

Comment: **non-const** reference